# Trouble with setting up OpenCV CUDA

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson

Righto, I'm getting this issue... cv::cuda::getDeviceEnabledCount() == 0

Platform Specifications:

-Jetson TX2

-Ubuntu 16.04

-OpenCV 3.4.2

I have a usr/local/cuda folder. I just reinstalled OpenCV by grabbing the newest release from GitHub, cmaking and then making it.

If I manage to figure it out, I'll be sure to update this.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didi you have an actual question to ask? [SO] isn't a microbloggibg service.

Comment: https://elinux.org/Jetson_TX2#Computer_Vision

Answer (score -1):

I set the cmake "WITH_CUDA" flag to on in the opencv folder I DL'd. Fixed me up m880s